# Localization does not work on some projects

Tags: c#, localization, cultureinfo

I am trying to make my project multilingual. To do this, I created resource files for English and for other languages, for example:

langu.resx
langu.uk-UA.resx

In some of my projects, everything works fine. But some projects don't want to change the language.

With this `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` returns the correct culture

I tried changing the language in the program with the following code:

```
ResourceManager RM = new ResourceManager("PasteCurb.Properties.Lang.langu", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
              
               string day = RM.GetString("btnApplyText");

               CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("uk-UA");

               string dayrr = RM.GetString("btnApplyText",ci);
```

But in the variable dayrr, I get the value in English, instead of Ukrainian.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Set the culture info like below and than you can access a text string by the name:

```cs
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("uk-UA");              
var text = Properties.Resources.btnApplyText;
```

When you access resources directly by using the `ResourceManager` be sure that the root name of the resource file is defined correctly. By default the root name doesn't include the language identifier.

It should look like below:

```cs
var rm = new ResourceManager("PasteCurb.Properties.Resources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
string dayrr = rm.GetString("btnApplyText", new CultureInfo("uk-UA"));
```

For more information see [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it didn't help. I am writing an application for Autodesk Revit. Calling this command changed the language for other buttons (dll). But not for the problematic one.

Comment: @Andrii: Yes, this change the culture used by the current thread. Isn't that what you want to do? You wrote: _"With this System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture returns the correct culture"_. So, why you are creating an additional `CultureInfo` object to load string if your thread already returns proper `CurrentUICulture`? **Update your question to describe more precisely what is you want to achieve.**